# How to Calculate Levenshtein distance between two .txt files?

Tags: python, linux, levenshtein-distance

Is there a standard linux command for it? If not, can anyone describe a python script to do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not recommend doing that.
The Levenshtein Distance function has a complexity of almost O(n*m) which is kind of O(n²) when the texts are similar.

But if you want to you could do it...
`pip install python-Levenshtein`

and the code will be something like that:

```py
from Levenshtein import *

txt1 = open("text1.txt").read()
txt2 = open("text2.txt").read()

print("distance:", distance(txt1,txt2))
```

Comment: Great. worked :). Do you have a better method then to compare two files? I am comparing output of two ocr programs.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. When the ocr Outputs are similar and there are one few differences to expect, yout could do a "split" and compare each word/line etc.
And only use levenshtein distance for the part in wich diferences occur when the amount of lines are the same. eg:

```
def textLevi(txt1,txt2):
   lines = list(zip(txt1.split("\n"),txt2.split("\n")))
   distance = 0
   for i,ele in enumerate(lines,1):
        line1,line2 = ele
       if line1 != line2:
           actDistance = distance(line1,line2)
           print( "Distance of line %d: " %(i),actDistance)
           distance += actDistance


   print( "Sum of Lv Distances:",distance)
 
textLevi("Hello I \n like cheese","Hello I \n like cheddar")
```

would create the Output:

> Distance of line 2:  4
>
> Sum of Lv Distances: 4